# Entity Framework Custom Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Well, i tried to implement custom annotation for EF 6 just as explained in [a tutorial by Milinaudara](https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/case-sensitive-search-using-entity-framework-with-custom-annotation/) as it is the first google hit i found. The tutorial is pretty much easy to follow. But, it looked like i will need to add `[CaseSensitive]` annotation on a column after i ran the first migration - [creating table](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/15de49003c43365307408b408dc57252847f9803/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs#L373) - and the `[CaseSensitive]` will be actually executed at a second migration as [**alter table**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/15de49003c43365307408b408dc57252847f9803/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs#L477) operation. Am I wrong? Because it's what i've experienced so far..

Is it possible for that annotation to be run at table creation? Should i override EF's `Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)` method to ensure the `[CaseSensitive]` annotation actually get applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)` only got called when the model changed and never get fired on table creation or adding a new column - perhaps this is pretty obvious but the tutorial did not mention it.. at least a background story on each methods will be better.. I end up overriding `Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)` and `Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)` so it looked like:

```
protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
{
    //add the column
    base.Generate(addColumnOperation);

    //alter the column
    this.Generate(new AlterColumnOperation(addColumnOperation.Table, addColumnOperation.Column, false));
}

protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
{
    //add the column
    base.Generate(createTableOperation);

    //alter the column
    foreach(ColumnModel column in createTableOperation.Columns)
    {
        this.Generate(new AlterColumnOperation(createTableOperation.Name, column, false));
    }
}
```

Although i know we should never assume every alter operation is safe.. so, passing `false` when constructing `AlterColumnOperation` might be a bad idea.